# Return boolean observable on angular guard

Tags: angular, promise, observable, angular-router-guards, canactivate

I would like to block URL access from unauthorized users.
I'm currently using canActivate with route Guard from angular to block users to access /my/specific_url_route.

Indeed, I want to block some users (not listed in a list on my database) from accessing the resource by typing the matching URL (like: *mydomain/legalForm/123ytfdhs653HG*). To do that, first of all, I already block the access from my user view (OK) but the unauthorized users can still access the resource (page) by typing the correct URL directly (the subject).

My code is correct (return false and true as expected on my service) but my guard

> canActivate()

is executed and returns a value before my function has been completed. **I know that's an issue relative to promise/observable**. I need to edit my 2 functions *canActivate()* and *isAuthorizedToAccessForms0()*, but I don't know how to expect the correct behavior.

**I know that `pipe`, `map` or `then` should be added** after my called to function in order to wait for the result in my guard, here are related [subject 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335950/delay-the-route-canactivate-method-call-till-backend-service-return-result-in-an) [subject 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function) [subject 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69194766/delay-canactivate-call-when-page-refreshes-in-order-to-wait-for-the-data-to-load)

My service:

```
  public isAuthorizedToAccessForms0(id): boolean{ 
    var isFound = false;
    
    //query
    this.fire.collection('solutions').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', id).get().then(val => {
      val.forEach(v => {
        this.emailsAuthorizedVeolia = v.data().emailVeoliaAuthorized; //get each user
      })
    }).then(res => {
      //Check if a user is present in the list (whenever his position is in the list)
      for (let i = 0; i <= this.emailsAuthorizedVeolia.length-1 ; i++) {
        if(this.authService.currentUserEmail === this.emailsAuthorizedVeolia[i]) {
            isFound = true
          } else {
            //isFound = false by default
          }
      }
    }).then(final => {
      if (isFound === false) { //no occurrence finded
        console.log("DENIED!")
        isFound = false
        return false
      } else { //user finded
        console.log("GRANTED!")
        isFound = true
        return true
      }
    });
    
    return isFound;
  }
```

My guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const myId = route.paramMap.get('id')
    
    try{
        const authorized = this.formAllServ.isAuthorizedToAccessForms(myId) //HERE I need to add .pipe ? .then ? .map ?
        
        if(authorized === false) {
            console.log("FALSE")
            alert('You are not allowed to view this page');
            this.router.navigate(['/homeUser']);
            return false
        }
        else {
            console.log("TRUE")
            alert('Access granted !');
            return true
        }
    } catch(err) {
        return false;
    }  
    
}
```

Comment: You need to change both functions; `isAuthorizedToAccessForms0` needs to return an `Observable<boolean>` because it can't return `boolean` like it pretends to now. Once you get that working, you can return `this.formAllServ.isAuthorizedToAccessForms0(myId).pipe(map((isAuthorized: boolean) => ...` and do what you need to do. I suggest reviewing [the documentation on Observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable).

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, in fact I was returning a simple boolean, that's why I couldn't get my result on my guard ! It's better by returning Observable<boolean>. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `isAuthorizedToAccessForms0` method. You return the `isFound` variable without waiting for end of the promise. Accordingly, the result of this function will always be `false`.

You can update code of `isAuthorizedToAccessForms0` like that:

```
 public isAuthorizedToAccessForms0(id): Observable<boolean> { 
    
    return new Observable<boolean>(observer => {
      this.fire.collection('solutions').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', id).get().then(val => {
        val.forEach(v => {
          this.emailsAuthorizedVeolia = v.data().emailVeoliaAuthorized; //get each user
        })
      }).then(res => {
        //Check if user is present in the list (whenever his position in the list)
        for (let i = 0; i <= this.emailsAuthorizedVeolia.length-1 ; i++) {
          if(this.authService.currentUserEmail === this.emailsAuthorizedVeolia[i]) {
              console.log('GRANTED!');
              observer.next(true);
              observer.complete();
              break;
            } else {
              observer.next(false);
              observer.complete();
              console.log('DENIED!');
              break;
              //isFound = false by default
            }
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

After that you should update the guard

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const myId = route.paramMap.get('id')
    
    try{
       return this.formAllServ.isAuthorizedToAccessForms(myId).pipe(
        tap((authorized) => {
 
          if(authorized === false) {
            console.log("FALSE")
            alert('You are not allowed to view this page');
            this.router.navigate(['/homeUser']);
        }
        else {
            console.log("TRUE")
            alert('Access granted !');
        }
        })
       )
       
    } catch(err) {
        return of(false);
    }  
    
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you so much that works as expected. I'm now able to get back my result (true or flase) from my function (service) and impact changes on my guard.  It's better by returning Observable<boolean>. Thanks a lot !